# Lubuntu 16.04 - indicator applet area of the LXPanel won't work

Tags: lubuntu, 16.04, indicator, applet, lxpanel

The icons of the indicators and applications (e.g. nm-applet or Telegram) disappeared from the LXPanel's indicator applet area (but the area is still there but doesn't show anything).

How can I restore the original function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could solve the problem with the full removal and reinstallation of the lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin package.

Comment: I couldn't remove `lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin` because that would have removed `lubuntu-desktop`, so instead I reinstalled it and issued the command `lxpanelctl restart`. That worked for me, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions proposed by G.P. and Paddy Landau have not worked for me.

All there is in the applet indicator area is the statement 'No Indicators'.

Meantime, I am using tint2 panel, otherwise I would not be able to connect to the internet.